# Python scaling with 4D data

Tags: python, scale

I have a python 4D array with a general structure of:

```
tdata = [sample, x, y, channel]
```

with overarching dimensions of [10000, 5, 5, 12]

and I would like to do either a minmaxscaler, or a standardscaler on the data. The problem is that both scalers only accepts 2D data. If I wanted to scale across each [x,y] 2D channel for every sample, is there an efficient way of doing this opposed to trying:

```
for i in range(0,len(sample)):
    for j in range(0,len(channel)):
        transformed_tdata[i,:,:,j] = scaler.fit(tdata[i,:,:,j])
```

But then wouldn't each sample be independently scaled for each channel?

Comment: Do you want each sample-channel pair to have a separate scaler or do you a single max-min scalar for all the 'coordinates'?

Comment: The hope would be for: [:,:,:,j] to have the same scaler applied. In other words, each channel would have its own individual scaler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you want a scaler for each channel, you can reshape each channel of the data to be of shape (10000, 5*5). Each channel  (which was previously 5x5) is now a length 25 vector, and the scaler will work. You'll have to transform your evaluation data in the same way with the scalers in `channel_scalers`.

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
n_channels = 12

tdata = np.random.rand(10000, 5, 5, n_channels)
tdata_transformed = np.zeros_like(tdata)

channel_scalers = []

for i in range(n_channels):
    mmx = MinMaxScaler()
    slc = tdata[:, :, :, i].reshape(10000, 5*5) # make it a bunch of row vectors
    transformed = mmx.fit_transform(slc)
    transformed = transformed.reshape(10000, 5, 5) # reshape it back to tiles
    tdata_transformed[:, :, :, i] = transformed # put it in the transformed array
    channel_scalers.append(mmx) # store the transform
```

Comment: on the line with 'slc = slc.reshape(10000,5,5)', shouldn't this be 'slc = transformed.reshape(10000,5,5)' ?